# Attitude and orbit thrusters catalog

Tags: spacecraft, propulsion, attitude, astrodynamics

Typically, when trying to adjust simulation parameters (of orbit control, attitude control...) to real world values in order to validate algorithms with comparisons with past and current mission performances I sometimes face difficulties to find those real world thrusters values.

I wonder: has someone made a catalog compiling past and current thrusters characteristics and in what missions they were used?

Note: I am not interested in launchers boosters values, but in AOCS thrusters.

Comment: Astronautix.com and heroicrelics.org have a lot of information, but not consistently organized.

Comment: Well, at least is something. Although as you said they are a bit disorganized